# parametros twig symfony

Tags: get, twig, router, symfony4

Mi problema consiste en pasar un Id usando get para editar un usuario
estoy usando el framework symfony con plantillas de twig la informacion es la siguiente.

Plantilla twig

```
<th class="text-center"> <a class="btn btn-primary button"  href="{{ path('client_edit', {'id':client.id })}}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a> </th>
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

public function editAction(Request $request){

```
   $search = $request->query->get('id');
    var_dump($search);
    die();
```

}

El router

```
client_edit:
path: /edit/{id}
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Client:edit"}
methods: GET
```

en la Url muestra el id del usuario seleccionado pero en el controlador el dato me aparece nulo

gracias por la atencion

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás accediendo a los parámetros query de la petición. Por ejemplo en tu caso cuando haces: 
 `$request->query->get('id');` Lo que haces es buscar el id en la ruta: /edit/1?**id=1**
Para acceder a los parámetros de la ruta puedes utilizar: 
`$request->attributes->get('id');`
O bien dentro del propio controlador ponerlo como parámetro:

```
public function editAction(int $id): Response
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas accesar a datos de la sesion directamente en TWIG, puedes hacerlo con:

```
app.user
```

Esto funciona en Symfony 5.

Esta en la documentacion mira:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable